# Get Firefox PDF viewer information

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, firefox, pdf

I have a web application written in c# that shows pdf documents.
What I do is when a user click a document, I open a new browser tab and show the pdf.

Everything works fine but in Firefox i have a boring problem.
If the PDF viewing option is set to 'Preview in Firefox' goes fine, otherwise the browser downloads the aspx page where the document should be shown.

[image]

Is it possible via javascript or c# code know what option is set and so manage the situation in a proper way?

Comment: I just add in the header the 'content-length', but i do not actually download the document, i just show it in the browser.

Comment: Yes exactly. It works in every browser, even in Firefox, but only if the 'preview in Firefox' is enabled otherwise it downloads automatically the aspx page.
Sample code:

System.Net.WebClient User = new System.Net.WebClient();
Byte[] Ffle_Buffer = User.DownloadData(path_doc);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.AddHeader("content-length", Ffle_Buffer.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(Ffle_Buffer);

Comment: Could you please try to add `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");`

Comment: No, nothing. It always works in the same way.